# Magento 2: Can't complete checkout because of unexpected character of the JSON data

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, json

After filling the shipping information in the first step of checkout, I click on the "Continue" button and the site stops responding. The spinning wheel appears but it is not possible to click on anything else.

It seems the cause of this issue is a "uffef" character inserted somehow in a file. See image attached to see more information obtained from the page inspector in Firefox.

How can I find the file to edit so I can remove that character?

EDIT - JSON response added:

```
{
    "payment_methods":[
        {
            "code":"cashondelivery",
            "title":"Pago en Oxxo \/ 7-Eleven"
        },
        {
        "code":"banktransfer",
        "title":"Dep\u00f3sito o transferencia bancaria"
        }
    ],
    "totals":
    {
    "grand_total":489,
    "base_grand_total":489,
    "subtotal":359,
    "base_subtotal":359,
    "discount_amount":0,
    "base_discount_amount":0,
    "subtotal_with_discount":359,
    "base_subtotal_with_discount":359,
    "shipping_amount":130,
    "base_shipping_amount":130,
    "shipping_discount_amount":0,
    "base_shipping_discount_amount":0,
    "tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,
    "weee_tax_applied_amount":null,
    "shipping_tax_amount":0,
    "base_shipping_tax_amount":0,
    "subtotal_incl_tax":359,
    "shipping_incl_tax":130,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax":130,
    "base_currency_code":"MXN",
    "quote_currency_code":"MXN",
    "items_qty":1,
    "items":[{
        "item_id":815,
        "price":359,
        "base_price":359,
        "qty":1,
        "row_total":359,
        "base_row_total":359,
        "row_total_with_discount":0,
        "tax_amount":0,
        "base_tax_amount":0,
        "tax_percent":0,
        "discount_amount":0,
        "base_discount_amount":0,
        "discount_percent":0,
        "price_incl_tax":359,
        "base_price_incl_tax":359,
        "row_total_incl_tax":359,
        "base_row_total_incl_tax":359,
        "options":"[]",
        "weee_tax_applied_amount":null,
        "weee_tax_applied":null,
        "name":"Playera Test"
    }],
    "total_segments":[{
        "code":"subtotal",
        "title":"Subtotal",
        "value":359
        },
        {
            "code":"shipping",
            "title":"Shipping & Handling (Est\u00e1ndar - 1 a 4 d\u00edas h\u00e1biles)",
            "value":130
        },
        {
            "code":"tax",
            "title":"Impuestos",
            "value":0,
            "extension_attributes":{
                "tax_grandtotal_details":[]
            }
        },
        {
            "code":"grand_total",
            "title":"Total",
            "value":489,
            "area":"footer"
        }
    ]}
}
```

[image: shipping-information XHR response]

Comment: can you share the JSON response please

Comment: What is that before `{"payment_methos"`?

Comment: I think it is a "ufeff" character. I don't know why it's there. It seems to be a problem caused by a file with wrong encoding, and I think that is causing the issue

Comment: I added JSON response. As stated before, it seems the problem is caused by that "ufeff" character at the beginning, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: yes, I think that is the issue, I do not understand why that is there.

Comment: have you added any module related to payment or checkout.

Comment: there is a nice explanation on this character in below post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070677/ufeff-invalid-character-in-identifier?rq=1 you can check this, hope this helps!